# Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close when switch pages with pageview

Tags: flutter

I'm not sure if I initialized the bloc correctly but it keeps having the same problem when I switch pages **Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close**. I assume the problem is in the cubits but not entirely sure how to go about it. I also use pageview which wraps the CameraPage and the HomePage in a wrapper, I'm not sure if it's a problem.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:at_app1/core/common/cubits/app_user/app_user_cubit.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/core/utils/camera_utils.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/core/utils/permission_utils.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/presentation/pages/auth_page.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/presentation/pages/login_or_register.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/presentation/pages/temp_home_page.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/init_dependencies.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/post/presentation/bloc/camera_bloc.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/post/presentation/bloc/camera_event.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/themes/dark_mode.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/themes/light_mode.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/presentation/bloc/auth_bloc.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  await initDependecies();
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<AppUserCubit>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (_) => serviceLocator<AuthBloc>()),
      BlocProvider(create: (context) => CameraBloc(
        cameraUtils: CameraUtils(), 
        permissionUtils: PermissionUtils())
        ..add(const CameraInitialize(recordingLimit: 15))),
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  /*@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthIsUserLoggedIn());
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const AuthPage(),
      theme: lightMode,
      darkTheme: darkMode,
      /*routes: {
          '/login_register_page': (context) => const LoginOrRegisterPage(),R
          '/users_page': (context) => const UsersPage(),
          '/home_page': (context) => const HomePage(),
          '/profile_page': (context) => ProfilePage(),
          '/forgot_password_page': (context) => const ForgotPasswordPage(),
          '/following_post_page': (context) => const FollowingPostPage(),
          '/create_post_page': (context) => const CameraExampleHome(),
          '/search_page': (context) => const SearchPage(),
          '/saved_page': (context) => const SavedPage(),
          '/settings_page': (context) => SettingsPage(),
          '/message_page': (context) => MessagePage(),
          '/screen_wrapper': (context) => ScreenWrapper(),
        }*/
    );
  }
}
```

cubits

```
import 'package:at_app1/core/common/entities/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'app_user_state.dart';

class AppUserCubit extends Cubit<AppUserState> {
  AppUserCubit() : super(AppUserInitial());

  void updateUser(User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      emit(AppUserInitial());
    } else {
      emit(AppUserLoggedIn(user));
    }
  }
}
```

init_dependencies

```
import 'package:at_app1/core/common/cubits/app_user/app_user_cubit.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/core/utils/camera_utils.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/core/utils/permission_utils.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/data/data_source/auth_remote_data_source.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/data/repository/auth_repository_impl.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/domain/repository/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/domain/usecases/current_user.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/domain/usecases/user_login.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/domain/usecases/user_sign_up.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/auth/presentation/bloc/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:at_app1/features/post/presentation/bloc/camera_bloc.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

final serviceLocator = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> initDependecies() async {
  _initAuth();
  _initCameraBloc();
  final supaBase = await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://prxovcnwshtjnzvysoxa.supabase.co',
    anonKey:
        'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6InByeG92Y253c2h0am56dnlzb3hhIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MTAwMzg2NTQsImV4cCI6MjAyNTYxNDY1NH0.8wmzzkc3mBS8AXIPPmJYQEUC3aD4Tk70fp2YQ59nG90',
  );

  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(() => supaBase.client);

  //core
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(() => AppUserCubit());
}

void _initAuth() {
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<AuthRemoteDataSource>(
      () => AuthRemoteDataSourceImpl(serviceLocator()));

  serviceLocator.registerFactory<AuthRepository>(
      () => AuthRepositoryImpl(serviceLocator()));

  serviceLocator
      .registerFactory<UserSignUp>(() => UserSignUp(serviceLocator()));

  serviceLocator.registerFactory<UserLogin>(() => UserLogin(serviceLocator()));

  serviceLocator
      .registerFactory<CurrentUser>(() => CurrentUser(serviceLocator()));

  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(() => AuthBloc(
      userSignUp: serviceLocator(),
      userLogin: serviceLocator(),
      currentUser: serviceLocator(),
      appUserCubit: serviceLocator()));
}

void _initCameraBloc() async {
  // Register CameraBloc with GetIt
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(() => CameraBloc(
      cameraUtils: CameraUtils(), 
      permissionUtils: PermissionUtils()));
}
```